# How can I write my exported XML to an XML File?

Tags: java, xml

My job is to search for a book on WikiBooks and export the corresponding XML file. This file should be edited later. However, the error occurs earlier.
My idea was to read the page and write it line by line to an XML file. Here is my code for it:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Welches Buch wollen Sie suchen?");
    book = (reader.readLine());
    book = replaceSpace(book);

    URL url = new URL("https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Spezial:Exportieren/" + book);
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
    uc.connect();

    BufferedReader xmlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    File file = new File("wiki.xml");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = xmlReader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    xmlReader.close();
```

The code is executed without an error message, but the saved file ends in the middle of a word and is therefore incomplete.
How can I work around this problem?

Comment: First: you get binary data, but convert it to strings (readers) and back, which is unnecessary and a likely source for problems (but probably not the specific problem that you have). Try to avoid using `String`/`char[]`/`Reader` and `Writer` when all you do is shuffle data from A to B. Use `byte[]`/`InputStream`/`OutputStream` and possibly `ByteBuffer` instead. Second: you never close the `FileWriter`, which could be the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested the problem is that the content of the stream is not flushed to the file. If you call `close()` on your `writer` the content is automatically flushed to the file.

Here is your code with the added statement in the end:

```
BufferedReader xmlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
File file = new File("wiki.xml");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = xmlReader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(inputLine + "\n");

}
writer.close();
xmlReader.close();
```

A much easier solution that is built into Java is using the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class. My suggestion is that you replace the above code with the following simple statement, which directly stores your `InputStream` into a file and automatically takes care of the streams.

```
Files.copy(uc.getInputStream(), Paths.get("wiki.xml"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```